# Does calling a stdio function result in a system call every time?

Tags: c, linux

For example `puts()` calls the system call `write()`.
Does that mean it calls `write()` every time we call `puts()`, or does puts accumulate into some buffer before calling `write()`?

Comment: If you see it on the screen then it is not buffered.

Comment: Nope, `puts()` doesn't always invoke a system call. The C stdio library for Unix buffers output, and normally writes out the buffer (a system call) if (a) it goes to a terminal, and (b) a newline is written (as `puts(3)` does). If stdout isn't a terminal, it is just buffered until the buffer is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right -- typically C `FILE*` streams do have buffers that store data.  Only when the buffer is full, or the stream is closed, or `fflush` is called, do they make a Unix I/O system call.  You can control the buffering of a stream with the C standard function [`setvbuf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setvbuf.html).

Answer (score 3):

The stdio functions do utilise buffering.  In the specific case of `puts()`, it always writes a complete line to `stdout`, and if `stdout` is connected to a terminal then it will usually be line-buffered, so each call to `puts()` will result in a call to `write()`.

However, it is possible to have `stdout` be fully buffered - either using `setvbuf()` (as long as this is done before any other operations on `stdout`), or more commonly by running the program with `stdout` attached to a pipe or file.  In this case, each call to `puts()` will not necessarily result in a call to `write()`.